# Kerberos connection error to Hive2 using JDBC in R

Tags: r, jdbc, hive

I used to be able to run R code to pull Hive table using JDBC under Cloudera CDH 4.5. However now I got below connection error after upgraded to CDH5.3 (failed 
to find any Kerberos tgt), seems it can not to connect to Cluster anymore. 
The Hive server has been upgraded to hive2 server/Beeline.
Please see the code and error log below. Any experience and advise on how to fix this? Thanks.

```
options(width=120)                                                  
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )              
query="select * from Hive_table"   
user="user1"  
passw="xxxxxxx"  
hiveQuerytoDataFrame<-function(user,passw,query){
  library(RJDBC)           
  .jaddClassPath("/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.10.0-cdh5.3.3.jar")    
  drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",classPath = list.files("/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T, recursive = TRUE),identifier.quote="`")        
`conn <- dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:hive2://server.domain.<>.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server.domain.com@SERVER.DOMAIN.COM",user,passw)                        
  #dbListTables(conn)          
  jdbc_out<-dbGetQuery(conn,query)             
  str(jdbc_out)     
  return(jdbc_out)   
}  `

**Log:
ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]**`
```

Comment: **1** How do you set your Kerberos ticket before running that script: with `kinit`on Linux? with the MIT Kerberos GUI on Windows? **2** since you specify Kerberos authentication in the URL the "user" and "password" args are irrelevant, you can put empty strings instead **3**  Is that a Hive *0.10* JDBC driver that you set in CLASSPATH?!? nothing more recent in the CDH distro?

Comment: Samson, I used kinit on Linux.  You mean hive-jdbc-0.10 is too old, i will need to check our system admin to see if there is new version. thanks